# Using specific class type reference in Delphi attribute-constructor

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

As Delphi cannot handle attributes on enum-values, I tried another approach. TMyEnum is my enum. Class TMyEnumLabelProvider provides the labels I need. I link the enum-type with an attribute to its labelprovider. This doesn't compile however. I cannot define the provider fully before referencing its classtype since it uses TMyEnum in one of its methods.

```
TEnumLabelProviderCallback = procedure(Context: TObject; 
                                       Index: integer; 
                                       const Name: string) of object;

TEnumLabelProvider = class abstract
public
    procedure Iterate(Context: TObject; 
                      Callback: TEnumLabelProviderCallback); virtual; abstract;
end;

TEnumLabelProviderClass = class of TEnumLabelProvider;

TEnumLabelProviderAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
private
    FProviderClass: TEnumLabelProviderClass;
public
    constructor Create(ProviderClass: TEnumLabelProviderClass);
    property ProviderClass: TEnumLabelProviderClass read FProviderClass;
end;

TMyEnumLabelProvider = class;

{$SCOPEDENUMS ON}

[TEnumLabelProvider(TMyEnumLabelProvider)]
TMyEnum = (MyEnum0,
           MyEnum1,
           MyEnum2);
{$SCOPEDENUMS OFF}

// This is where the compilation fails.....
TMyEnumLabelProvider = class(TEnumLabelProvider)
public
    class function GetLabel(MyEnum: TMyEnum): string;
    procedure Iterate(Context: TObject; Callback: TEnumLabelProviderCallback); override;
end;
```

Any ideas on how to do this properly. For now I workaround by declaring GetLabel(MyEnum: integer), but obviously I prefer being type strict.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On second thought I could solve this problem by using a class helper. Not really elegant but better than using int:

`TMyEnumLabelProvider = class(TEnumLabelProvider)
    public
        procedure Iterate(Context: TObject; Callback: TEnumLabelProviderCallback); override;
    end;

    [TEnumLabelProvider(TMyEnumLabelProvider)]
    TMyEnum = (MyEnum0,
               MyEnum1,
               MyEnum2);

    TMyEnumLabelProviderHelper = class helper for TMyEnumLabelProvider
    public
        class function GetLabel(MyEnum: TMyEnum): string;
    end;`

Comment: Excuse me, but I am not able to find out what you are trying to accomplish. For instance: what do you mean by "enum labels"?

Comment: @UweRaabe I think he means the strings attached to enum elements that are displayed in the UI. Think of a binding framework for example.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe: Smasher is quite right. That's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Smasher, then why not use [RegisterIntegerConsts](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.RegisterIntegerConsts)

Comment: @UweRaabe why do you ask me? Post it as an answer as it might be what the OP looks for.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe: RegisterIntegerConsts would do the trick. Perhaps just a matter of taste, but i prefer the helper approach.

Comment: Isn't const ENUM_LABELS: array[TMyEnum] = ('LabelA', 'LabelB', 'LabelC'); enough?

Comment: I don't see how your helper class helps. To call a method provided by the helper class, the compiler needs to know that you're calling a method on a TMyEnumLabelProvider specifically, not just any TEnumLabelProvider descendant. For the compiler to know that, you'd have to type-cast to that type. If you're type-casting to that type, then you don't need attributes to discover the provider type at run time since you already know the type at compile time. Back to your original question: What compiler error do you get?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: The compiler says: Incompatible types 'TClass' and 'class of TMyEnumLabelProvider'. I need to define TMyEnumLabelProvider completely before referencing its type for TEnumLabelProviderAttribute. The helper class enables me to split up the definition in 2 parts. No cast involved.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: No cast involved, because Iterate provides a generic method to retrieve all labels without actually knowing what type they are.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use a static array of string to store the labels as defined below. you can then simply index the array using the enum to get the label required.

```
type
  TMyEnum = (MyEnum0, MyEnum1, MyEnum2);

const
  EnumLabels : array[TMyEnum] of string = ('MyEnumLabel0', 'MyEnumLabel1', 'MyEnumLabel2');
```